# How to run a GUI program as a different user (Debian)?

Tags: debian, sudo, root, gui, su

Using a terminal, I can change the running user with `su` and `sudo` — but how can I do that by clicking on an icon/shortcut on the desktop/start menu?

If I have to be root to execute I will be asked anyway, but some programs e.g. `Krusader` and `NetBeans` sometimes run without root access but then you can't accomplish what you want.

On Windows I simply hit shift and rightclick on it and am prompted for user and password. I guess there is a similarly simple way to do that in Debian as well. (Apart from workarounds like creating scripts such as `sudo xyz`.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, don't use `sudo` or `su` to change users to run a graphical process, or you're liable to have problems down the line (`~/.ICEauthority` changing owner is a notable issue). Instead, create a shortcut that uses the following command:

```
gksu -u [user] command
```

`gksu` launches a graphical prompt for the user's password, and upon entering the correct password, launch the application as the user specified.

Comment: What does `gksu` do differently from `sudo` so that it works better?

Answer (score 2):

my own solution involves `ssh`. when I want to run `<command>` under a different user `<login>`, I do this:

`ssh -CY <login>@0 <command>`

yes, I do need a ssh server in place and I do need to either enter the other user password or to have my own public key in `~<login>/.ssh/authorized_keys2`. and I cannot close the terminal from which I gave the command.