# Stuck installing TexLive from scratch on Debian KDE!

Tags: software-installation, perl, latex

I'm trying to install TexLive 2013 on my Debian 7.3 kde desktop from scratch. I've read these guides ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) & [2](http://zeronteproject.com/113/)) but instead of getting the perltk installer's GUI, I get the txt mode installer which I don't like because I don't know how to move around with it. I don't want the +3.2 GB installation, only some packages and I want to have the GUI that gives me better control over the different packages I need from time to time.
So far this is what I've done

1. `wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz`
2. `tar -xvzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz`
3. `cd install-tl-20140123/`
4. `./install-tl -gui perltk`

The last command was given as root AFTER installing the `perl-tk` package from the repos (v. 1:804.030-1). However I get this back from the command line:

```
root@aliquis:/home/guest/install-tl-20140123# ./install-tl -gui perltk
No protocol specified
perl/Tk unusable, cannot create main window.
Error message from creating MainWindow:
couldn't connect to display ":0" at /usr/lib/perl5/Tk/MainWindow.pm line  53.
Tk::MainWindow->new() at ./install-tl line 339

Continuing in text mode...
```

What is wrong with `perl-tk`? Do I have to install some additional packages?

Comment: If you are `su root` inside another user's X session, that would explain *couldn't connect to display ":0"*.

Comment: If you are running in root on a terminal, but the desktop is owned by a user, you don't have permission to access the display / X server whatever. Probably nothing is wrong with perl. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21193/4671 BTW, I assume you are aware that Debian wheezy has TeX Live 2012, right?

Comment: So how do I get that nice blue-ish window as given [in this link](http://zeronteproject.com/113/)?

Comment: @WobbyWindows Try `gksu -u username ./install-tl -gui perltk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a simple permissions issue. The root user has no right to access your user's X session unless you allow him. So, either use `gksu` instead of switching to root:

```
gksu ./install-tl -gui perltk
```

Or, allow access to your X session before switching to root:

```
$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
$ sudo -i
```

Once you're done, log out of the root account and reactivate access control:

```
$ xhost -
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
```

Comment: I've tried `gksu ./install-tl -gui perltk` and got back `No protocol specified (gksu:4189): Gtk-WARNING **:cannot open display: :0` . When I tried with `$ xhost +` and then `sudo -i` it asked me the password for the current user (my user-name is *guest*, fyi). I got it wrong 3 times so it says now `guest is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported`. What is this? I have a kde desktop, should I write instead `su --`?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I got the graphical installer by doing as you said: 1) `xhost +` then 2) `su --`.